# How to win the race to unlock the AG Systems prototype in Wipeout 2048?

Tags: wipeout-2048

I am trying to unlock the AG Systems Prototype aircraft in Wipeout 2048 on PSVita.
To unlock it, one has to finish at least 2nd in the Rockway Stadium Race Prototype Challenge.

However, even though I trained a fair amount, I don't "get" how to efficiently drive this aircraft. I keep on running into the walls, losing speed, and all the opponents sooner or later disappear over the horizon. When taking a turn, shall I use the air-brake ? Release the X button ? Use the side-shift?

Also, when trying to turn my ship's direction often becomes unstable and I have to struggle on the left stick pressing left-right-left etc to get it back in line.. Any advices on how to efficiently drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried a new approach to this race.

First, in the options menu I set the "Pilot Assist" to "Extreme".
Then, I learned how to take the skill cuts in Rockway Stadium and decided to try to use the maximum of them during the race.
So I started an other race, took the first place early. That allowed me to get a lot of turbo items, because I was the first to get on the green bonus pads.

Result : I arrived first and thus managed to get the Elite Pass ! :D